# Sending data blink(1) device

Tags: javascript, webusb

I just started looking into webusb and trying to use it to turn on a [blink(1) mk2](https://blink1.thingm.com/). I am able to discover the device, open it, claim an interface and call `controlTransferOut`. The trouble I am now having is not knowing what data I should be sending it to cause it to flash or light up.

I have been using [this example](https://github.com/todbot/blink1/blob/master/chrome/blink1test1/blink1test1.js#L51) where someone has been able to control it using a Chrome extension using the `chrome.usb` interface as inspiration in trying to get it to work. I have written the following code:

```
const VENDOR_ID = 0x27b8;

navigator.usb.requestDevice({
  filters: [{
    vendorId: VENDOR_ID
  }]
}).then(selectedDevice => {
  device = selectedDevice;
  return device.open();
}).then(() => {
  return device.selectConfiguration(1);
}).then(() => {
  return device.claimInterface(0);
}).then(() => {
  return device.controlTransferOut({
    requestType: 'class',
    recipient: 'interface',
    request: 0x09,
    value: 1,
    index: 0
  });
}).then(() => {
  const r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0);
  const g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0);
  const b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0);
  // not entirely sure what is going on below...
  const fadeMillis = 500;
  const th = (fadeMillis / 10) >> 8;
  const tl = (fadeMillis / 10) & 0xff;

  const data = new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x63, r, g, b, th, tl, 0x00, 0x00]).buffer;
  return device.transferIn(1, data);
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This fails with a transfer error when calling `controlTransferOut`. However, if I change the `requestType` to standard, it then goes on to fail when calling `transferIn`.

How can I find out what data and what format the data needs to be in to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `data` in the first `controlTransferOut`. `transferIn` does not send data to the device, it receives it.

*Edited to add*: There is unfortunately no general way to determine the correct format is for data sent to or from a USB device if it is not implementing a standard device class. The blink(1) mk2 uses the HID protocol but the particular format of the feature reports it sends and receives are non-standard.

Comment: Looking at the [spec](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/#transfers) there is no data field on the `USBControlTransferParameters` object?

Comment: `data` is the 2nd parameter to `controlTransferOut`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I still can't get this to work. I'll have to just do more investigation into how the data needs to be formatted.